# Insert new values in Sub-Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this:

```
array( 
       'person0' => array( 'name'=>'name0','address'=>'address0' ), 
       'person1' => array( 'name'=>'name1','address'=>'address1' ),
       'person2' => array( 'name'=>'name2','address'=>'address2' ) 
     );
```

I want to change it like this. (just append a new value in each sub-array)

```
array( 
       'person0' => array( 'name'=>'name0','address'=>'address0','type'=>'type0' ), 
       'person1' => array( 'name'=>'name1','address'=>'address1','type'=>'type1' ), 
       'person2' => array( 'name'=>'name2','address'=>'address2','type'=>'type2' ) 
     );
```

Is there any related function in php to perform this action? What is the shortest way to do this. Is it possible without loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browse the PHP manual when you wonder if a function exists to do something... it probably does.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

I'd just write the loop, but you can use those functions if you don't want to.

Comment: Yes. These are the required functions.